# How to test the functionality of my application on a version of Windows OS for a different country?

Tags: windows, operating-system, country

I have tested my application on US windows release. How can I test the application functionality on a windows release of a different country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several methods.

Some editions of Windows, like Win10 pro and Win7 ultimate, allow you to change display language to whatever you like in control panel. You can therefore switch language of your PC. Just don’t forget to change all regional settings as well (language for non-unicode programs, date time and number formats) and reboot.

Or (I usually prefer this method) you could use virtualization, such as VMWare Workstation or MS HyperV, i.e. install that foreign windows on a virtual machine.

Or you can just install that foreign windows on another PC and test your app there.

**Update:** Personally, I’ve encountered following 2 globalization-related bugs in my apps most often.

1. Caused by comma `,` being the decimal separator.
2. Caused by right-to-left layout.

So, be sure to test on at least Spanish and Hebrew windows localizations.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful ! @Soonts